# How to send an int when using callback?

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, fragment

okay, so... I need to know which button I pressed so I can adjust some values in another fragment.

MainActivity = In here is the callback defined
Levels = Where you can select Level and if you select level 1, 2 or 3 The speelveldfragment need to know
Speelveldfragment = where you actually play

All the code works fine, I onyl need to know how I can change certain values within speelveldfragment depending on level selected

MainFragment:

```
    @Override
public void goToPage(String pageName) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
    switch(pageName){
        case "play":
            SpeelveldFragment speelveldFragment = new SpeelveldFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameApp, speelveldFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        case "hoofdmenu":
            MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
            //fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_left);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameApp, menuFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        case "levels":
            Levels levels = new Levels();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameApp, levels);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;

    }
}

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
```

Levels:

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_levels, container, false);

    btnOne = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    btnTwo = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
    btnThree = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnThree);

    btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallback.goToPage("play");
        }
    });

    btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallback.goToPage("play");
        }
    });

    btnThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallback.goToPage("play");
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Speelveldfragment:

```
//Code which has nothing to do with the problem
```

## EDIT1

Interface:

```
public interface GoToPageInterface {
void goToPage(String pageName);
void onButtonClicked(String buttonType, int levelNum);
}
```

Thats pretty much it, i tried some other stuff across the other classes, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send in another value to your callback. So for example, for btnOne you would do:

```
btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         //Here you send in an integer with your callback defining the level#
         mCallback.goToPage("play", 1);
     }
});
```

Your OnClickListeners are set up to only fire when a specific button is pressed, so you already know exactly what button the user clicked. So just send in some other data to your callback that tells it which OnClickListener was fired.

---

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**

You would have to redefine your callback to be something like this:

```
public interface YourMainFragmentCallback {
    void onButtonClicked(String buttonType, int levelNum);
}
```

Then you would store the `levelNum` int as a Fragment class variable and use it to select your level. So your callback implementation might look something like this:

```
public void onButtonClicked(String buttonType, int levelNum) {
    if(buttonType.equals("play")) {
        levelSelection = levelNum; //levelSelection is a class member variable
    }
}
```

Then you would just use your `levelSelection` variable to start whatever Fragment needs to be started to go to that level.

Comment: @MikeLammers - Why can't it be applied? Can you not redefine your callback for some reason?

Comment: think its working, but how can I recieve the value? (In the speelveldfragment)

Comment: @MikeLammers - See my edit above. It would be quite simple to do it this way. Feel free to ask more questions if you still don't understand. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: I feel like such a noob right now.... cant get it to work...
What should I put where??

Comment: Can you post your callback code? Show me your callback interface definition and your implementation in MainFragment and I'll show you what to do.